# Mapbox - Reverse Geocoding - multiple language response

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using Mapbox to Reverse geocode a latitude, longitude location and wanted the city name(Place name) response with multiple languages.

The documentation says,

'If more than one language tag is supplied, text in all requested languages will be returned'

But I'm getting the response only in the first language specified.

```
MapboxGeocoding.builder()
   .accessToken("xyz..."),
   .query(Point.fromLngLat(-123.1207, 49.2827)) 
   .languages("zh-CN,ru")
   .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_PLACE)
   .mode(GeocodingCriteria.MODE_PLACES)
   .build();
```

This returns the place name in Chinese and not Russian.

Documentation : https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/mapbox-java/libjava-services/4.0.0/index.html

Verison used: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.1.0' and also 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the Mapbox team. Apparently, this is a bug in their Mobile SDK but their API works fine. Have reported this here. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/issues/446